# How many days are required for neural network prediction of dax future?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, neural-networks, optimization

I am predicting the daily change of the dax future.

Input data I am using:

- Dax, vdax, euro bund spy500 close prices as returns
- 8 series from investor series having values between 5 and -5

This is trained using Matlab time series Neural Network with:

- Feed recurrent forwards=10
- Delays=10
- Hiddenlayer(neurons?)=10

**Questions:**

1. How many points are recommended for full set (train, val, test)? $2000$?, $200$?, $500$? 
   If Neural Network using more records is it more  likely for overfitting?
2. Is it bad to add more series?  Like ratios from above series? Will it be more noise and overfitting?

Answer (score 4):

The testing set´s size is ranging from 10% to 30% of the training set, and validation set's size is ~10% of the training set. To prevent risk of overﬁtting, the size of the training set must be at least ﬁve times the number of weights.
For a three-layers network it has be suggests that the hidden layer (neurons) should have approximately sqrt(inputNo.*outputNo.).

Regarding the delay window size, my understanding is it depends, there is a minimum of prediction error for a specific delay size. Refer this [paper](http://www.smartquant.com/references/NeuralNetworks/neural30.pdf) for more details.

I don't quite understand what do you mean by "add more series". If you are talking about adding the same series trend with different time range, I don't think it will cause overfitting very likely since you don't change the VC dimension and the weights but just adding more training data.